# query() is called again after notifyChange()

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I am using a custom content provider and a CursorLoader for displaying a list of elements in a fragment.

First the CursorLoader calls the ContentProvider's query() to get all elements stored in my Database. In my query() function I start a thread which does a WebService call to update the elements in my database. The thread is parsing the WebServices' response and calling my ContentProviders bulkInsert().

When my bulkInsert() is done, i call notifyChange().

Now here is whats happening: I see that after the notifyChange(), my ContentProvider's query() method is called again, which leads to a new WebService call and so on and so on.

Here my query() method in the ContentProvider:

```
...
    // Database query
    ticketCursor = mDb.query(TBL_TICKET_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
    // set Notification URI
    ticketCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), TICKET_CONTENT_URI);

    // WebService call --> This starts a new Thread for the WebService call
    asyncSoapQuery(where, uri);

    return ticketCursor;
```

My bulkInsert method looks like this:

```
    mDb.beginTransaction();
    for (ContentValues value : values) {
        mDb.insertWithOnConflict(table, null, value, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    }
    mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(TICKET_CONTENT_URI, null);

    mDb.endTransaction();

    return values.length();
```

So, my problem is that this causes an endless loop of webservice calls. I thought, that the notifyChange() is not calling the content provider's query() method again. I only want to do the WS call inside my query() again if the user hits "refresh" on my UI...
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but I'm using insert() instead of applyBatch() in the content provider. I manage to resolve my issue by changing

```
mDb.insertWithOnConflict(table, null, value, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

to

```
long rowId = mDb.insertWithOnConflict(table, null, value, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

My next step is to check if rowId is greater than zero. Only when it is greater than zero then execute

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange
```

So it is something like this:

```
if (rowId > 0) {
        notifyChange(uri);
        return uri;
    } else {

        return null;
    }
```